# Weakly dominated Nash equilibrium in a zero-sum game

Tags: game-theory

There is a zero sum game G where player one plays T and Player two plays y and z. However y dominates z and Nash Equilibrium in this game would be (Ty). How can I prove this? Is it possible with minimax theorem or brower fixed point theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to exhibit an example, such as
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Here, 1 plays the top row and 2 plays (indifferently) the left or the right column, but the left column is weakly dominated by the right column.

Comment: Will this example work in zero sum game?

Comment: It is a zero-sum game.

Comment: 1 only plays T out of two possible choices  :-)

Comment: If you prefer, delete the second row and you have a trivial game (where 1 has no choice to make) that satisfies your question. To my taste, this second solution is less attractive because 1 is not really playing.

Comment: No thanks. This is getting close to private tutoring. Good luck on your HW.