# Zero Sum Games and Weakly Dominated Strategies

Tags: game-theory

Can you eliminate weakly dominated strategies in a zero-sum game? If yes, why?

Doesn't the order of elimination matter.

(Normally, in ordinary games in strategic form, you can only eliminate strictly dominated strategies. And if you were to eliminate weakly dominated strategies, the order would matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar question where the accepted answer includes a zero sum game with a Nash Equilibrium where one player plays a weakly dominated strategy: [Weakly dominated Nash equilibrium in a zero-sum game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193169/weakly-dominated-nash-equilibrium-in-a-zero-sum-game)

In case that gets taken down, here is the game:

$$\begin{array}{r | c | c |}
& L & R \\ \hline
T & (1,-1) & (1,-1) \\ \hline
B & (1,-1) & (0,0) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We have that $(T,L)$ is a Nash Equilibrium even though $L$ is weakly dominated by $R$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please could you help in solving the following game (added as an answer to the question). It said somewhere that this game could be solved to find the optimal strategy and value by eliminating the weakly dominated strategy.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

How can this zero-sum game be solved?